# pop up show blank

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, actionfunction, popup

I have below piece of code where the function opens a new pop up with blank. But it should display headers atleast ( like Account Demographics:). Can someone give an idea why this happens. In a different copy of the page with some other changes , it working fine.

Code snippet:

```
   function getSurveyPopup(acctid) {

        alert('survey pop up'+acctid);
        $("#poptableBody").empty();
        if ($('#sliderbox').width() < 50) {
            $('#toggleBtn').click();
        }

        getSurveyDetailRecord(acctid);
        return false;
   }

   function getSurveyDetailRecord(id) {
       //alert('survey detail'+id);
       var acctId = '';
       var accountName = '';
       var addressLine = '';
       var addressCity = '';
       var retSurveydetailResult = '<br/>'+'<div style="font-size:14px;font-Weight:bold;margin:5px;text-indent:5px;text-align:Left;font-family: Arial;">Account Demographics:</div>';

       <apex:repeat value="{!AcctSurveyResults}" var="wrapAcct">
         acctId = '{!wrapAcct.acct.id}';             

         if(acctId == id)
         {
             accountName = escapeSpecialChars("{!wrapAcct.acct.Name}");
             <apex:repeat value="{!wrapAcct.address}" var="addr">
                    addressLine = escapeSpecialChars("{!addr.Name}");
                    addressCity = '{!addr.City_State_Zip__c}';                        
             </apex:repeat>

             var svyName = '';

             <apex:repeat value="{!wrapAcct.svyTgtRatingMap}" var="st">
                var svyHasVal = '{!wrapAcct.svyTgtRatingMap[st]}';
                var svyType = escapeSpecialChars("{!st}");
                Alert('Hi');
                var svyImg = '<img src = " '+((svyHasVal == 'true') ? '{!URLFOR($Resource.SurveyImages_ABV, 'Images/icon-OK.png')}' : '{!URLFOR($Resource.SurveyImages_ABV, 'Images/failed-icon.png')}') + '" />';
                svyName = svyName + svyImg +'    '  + svyType+'    ';                  
            </apex:repeat>

             retSurveydetailResult += '<div style="font-size:12px;font-Weight:bolder;margin:5px;text-indent:5px;text-align:left; font-family:Verdana;">'
                   + '<table style="font-size:12px;font-Weight:500;max-width: 250; color:Black;margin:5px;text-indent:0px; text-align:left; font-family:Verdana;">'
                   + '<tr><td>' + accountName + '</td></tr>'
                   + '<tr><td>' + addressLine + '</td></tr>'
                   + '<tr><td>' + addressCity + '</td></tr>'
                   + '</table>'
                   + '<br/>';


             retSurveydetailResult +=  svyName +'<hr/>';


             <apex:repeat value="{!wrapAcct.questResponses}" var="SvyDet">
                 var svyTypeQuest = escapeSpecialChars("{!SvyDet}");

                 retSurveydetailResult += '<div id="divTubing" style="font-size:14px;font-Weight:bold;margin:5px;text-indent:5px;text-align:Left;font-family:Verdana;">'+ svyTypeQuest + ':</div>'
                                          +'<table style="font-size:12px;margin: 5px; font-Weight:400;text-align:left;text-indent:5px;font-family:Verdana;">';
                 var count =0;                             
                 <apex:repeat value="{!wrapAcct.questResponses[SvyDet]}" var="qr">
                         var question = escapeSpecialChars("{!qr.Question_Text_vod__c}");
                         var questRes = '{!qr.Response_vod__c}';

                         if(questRes == ''){
                             questRes = escapeSpecialChars("{!SUBSTITUTE(qr.Text_vod__c,'"','\\"')}");
                         }
                         if(questRes == '')

                         {
                            questRes = questRes.replace('\"','\\"');
                            questRes = questRes.replace('\n','<br/>');
                            var fulldate = '{!qr.Date_vod__c}';
                            if( fulldate != '')
                            {
                              questRes = formatDate(fulldate);
                            }
                         }
                         if(questRes == ''){
                             var fulldate = '{!qr.Datetime_vod__c}';
                             if(fulldate != '')
                             {
                                 questRes = formatDate(fulldate);
                             }
                         }
                         if(questRes == ''){
                             questRes = '{!qr.Number_vod__c}';
                         }

                     if(count == 0){
                         retSurveydetailResult +=  '<tr><td><b>'+ question +'</b></td><td><b>' + questRes + '</b></td></tr>';
                     }else{
                         retSurveydetailResult +=  '<tr><td>'+ question +'</td><td>' + questRes + '</td></tr>';
                     }
                     count = count+1;                              
                 </apex:repeat>                    
                 retSurveydetailResult += '</table>'+'<hr/>';
             </apex:repeat>

        }
       </apex:repeat>

       //alert(retSurveydetailResult);

       var oTable = document.getElementById("popupTable");
       var tbody = document.createElement("tBody");

       while (oTable.hasChildNodes()) {
            oTable.removeChild(oTable.firstChild);
       }

       oTable.appendChild(tbody);
       var temp = tbody.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
       temp.innerHTML = retSurveydetailResult;
       tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, tbody);

   }
```

Comment: Check the browser debugger for any javascript errors that are being thrown and thus not making it to the code that injects your html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eric! Just got the reason. In a line it was Alert('Hi');
A in capital is not recognized by javascript